# How to save images from network to cache using Fetch and Cache API

Tags: javascript, caching, fetch, service-worker

I am working on service workers and in the fetch event, I want all the request save on my array but when I console log the *fetch(event.request)*, it only returns a promise. how can I save images all image request using fetch API. I am newbie in service worker. Please help. Thankyou.

```
  self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response){
            if(response){
                return response; // get the element from the cache
            }
            /*save the fetch(event.request) link to array*/
            return fetch(event.request);// How toget the element from the network
        })
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing is visualizing your response and other different is storing the response object (which is the sum of the actual content, i.e. the image, and the response headers).

For storing the complete response, you should use a [cache object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) and the [`put()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/put) method.

To visualize the body of the response, you need to call one of the [body methods](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#body) on the response.

If you want to store and visualize, you need to [`clone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone) the response since storing or getting the body renders the response unreadable.

Here is a link for a [fetch + update strategy](https://github.com/delapuente/pangolink/blob/master/app/sw.js#L27-L39). Anyway, I strongly recommend you to start with a Service Worker [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) or [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/#0).